# Why do I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to store a Array of Bytes?

Tags: java, arrays

Why do I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to store a Array of Bytes? Can you maybe explain to me why it doesn't work this way? How can I do it better without NullPointerException?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.Screenblocks_Data.set_Image(Screenblocks_Data.java:13)
    at desktop_share_client.ScreenBlocks.run(ScreenBlocks.java:120)
```

---

```
public class Screenblocks_Data implements java.io.Serializable {
    public int Screenblocks_Counter = 0;
    public int[][] positions = new int[200][2];
    public Jpeg[] sub_images = new Jpeg[200];

    public Screenblocks_Data() {

    }

    public void set_Image(byte[] temp_image) {
        sub_images[Screenblocks_Counter].set_sub_image(temp_image);
    }

    public byte[] get_Image(int position) {
        return sub_images[Screenblocks_Counter].sub_image;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Jpeg {

    public byte[] sub_image = null;

    public void set_sub_image(byte[] temp_image) {

        sub_image = new byte[temp_image.length];

        sub_image = temp_image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You just bought a bag  to carry 200 apples. But without filling the bag, you are trying to eat an apple :).

You never initialized zeroth (or `Screenblocks_Counter`th element) element. First you have to add element at zero position and then access it.

```
 sub_images[Screenblocks_Counter] = new Jpeg();
 sub_images[Screenblocks_Counter].set_sub_image(temp_image);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works that way! I thought I initialize it with: "public Jpeg[] sub_images = new Jpeg[200];" Why that doesn't work?

Comment: @Felix when you read `Jpeg` here it is a *reference* to an object and creating an array of references doesn't imply you are creating an array of objects.

Comment: Updated with a real world example. Hope that clears your concept.